# Derivative of a composite function of a matrix?

Tags: calculus, matrices

I am stuck on the following matrix calculus problem. I'm trying to calculate the derivative of the following function with respect to $\mathbf{L}$,

$$J(\mathbf{L}) = ||\mathbf{x}_k - \sum_{i=1}^M \mathbf{P}_i(\mathbf{L})\mathbf{x}_{k-i}||_2^2$$

where $\mathbf{x}_k$ is a vector of length $N$, and the subscript denotes different vectors of the same shape. $\mathbf{P}_i(\mathbf{L})$ is a function of $\mathbf{L}$, and I know what $\frac{\partial{\mathbf{P}_i(\mathbf{L})}}{\partial \mathbf{L}}$ is.

My problem is how to write $\frac{\partial{J(\mathbf{L})}}{\partial \mathbf{L}}$ in terms of $\frac{\partial{\mathbf{P}_i(\mathbf{L})}}{\partial \mathbf{L}}$?

I feel this is just chain rule and that I need to leverage the formula for the derivative of a composite function of a matrix, i.e. $\frac{\partial{f(\mathbf{P})}}{\partial{\mathbf{L}}}$ where $\mathbf{P} = g(\mathbf{L})$. There exists an identity to calculate this, $\frac{\partial{f(\mathbf{P})}}{\partial{\mathbf{L}}} = \mathrm{tr}[(\frac{\partial{f(\mathbf{P})}}{\partial{\mathbf{P}}})^T(\frac{\partial{\mathbf{P}}}{\partial{\mathbf{L}}_{ij}})]$, but the exact form of my problem (presence of summation and vectors) is leading to some confusion.

Would it be possible for someone to help me? Thank you!

Comment: It is just careful grind. Let $s$ denote the Euclidean norm squared, and $f$ the function inside the norm. Then $J = s \circ f$ and $DJ(L)H = D (n \circ f)(L) H = D n(f(L)) ( Df(L)H)= 2 f(L)^T ( Df(L)H)$. You have $Df(L)H = \sum_i  (D P_i(L)H) x_{k-i}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. Quick question though, what is matrix H in your notation?

Comment: The derivative is a linear map, so $DJ(L)H$ is the derivative in the direction $H$.